# Can't Connect to MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm following [this video tutorial on the MERN stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yTazHkDR4o&list=PLillGF-RfqbbiTGgA77tGO426V3hRF9iE&index=2) and I'm unable to connect to MongoDB for some very strange reason. This issue has been frustrating me quite a bit since I'm probably just missing something *very* basic, so please forgive me if the answer is painfully obvious to you.

The video uses mlab for MongoDB, which is no longer available, so I'm instead using MongoDB Atlas. The key I'm supposed to use to connect my application to the database is this:

`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@fs-shopping-list.6rzkd.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

My password doesn't contain any special characters, and my IP address is on the whitelist. As for `dbname`, I have one database named "data" with a collection called "items," so I'm using "data" for `dbname`.

The code in question that is causing my problem is in a file called `server.js`:

```
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI; // I keep my key in a separate file in the way shown in the video

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
    .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected.'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I keep getting this error when I try to run the server (I edited out my name from some of the paths):

```
{ MongooseServerSelectionError: bad auth Authentication failed.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/fs_shopping_list/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:828:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (/fs_shopping_list/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/fs_shopping_list/server.js:15:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
  message: 'bad auth Authentication failed.',
  reason:
   TopologyDescription {
     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
     setName: null,
     maxSetVersion: null,
     maxElectionId: null,
     servers:
      Map {
        'fs-shopping-list-shard-00-01.6rzkd.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
        'fs-shopping-list-shard-00-02.6rzkd.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
        'fs-shopping-list-shard-00-00.6rzkd.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
     stale: false,
     compatible: true,
     compatibilityError: null,
     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     commonWireVersion: null } }
```

Can someone please help me find out what I'm doing wrong so I can continue the tutorial? Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I don't think adding another account for database access will solve the problem, since [admin accounts on MongoDB have the ability to read and write to their databases](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/#database-user-privileges). The only thing I can think of that is possibly stopping me is maybe my Norton antivirus, although I'm not sure how to test this hypothesis.

Comment: If you are sure the URL is correct, do you maybe need to whitelist your IP?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using a database specific username and password, not the username / password to your Atlas management account, right?

Comment: I am using the username and password for my Atlas account that I use to log in to the website and see my clusters. I'm not sure what else to use.

Comment: you need to use username and password of your database user which you have created under Security -> Database Access

Comment: It says that the role for my account is "atlasAdmin@admin." I am sure I'm using the correct password in the URI string, so something very strange is going on for the authentication to fail...

Comment: I create a user for the database I am working on, then I use that user to connect to it and I do not give the /<dbname> in the URL. For example:
const dbUri = `mongodb+srv://${DBUSER}:${DBPASSWORD}@${DBSERVER}`

Comment: Try to connect with MongoDB Compass, it's free and almost foolproof since you get all the steps in the atlas ui. Also try to whitelist all IPs temporarily, just to make sure that's not the problem.

Comment: @ippi :( I tried using MongoDB Compass but it gave me the same "bad auth Authentication failed" message. Something must be wrong with my network or my URI string. This is the URI string I use: `mongodb+srv://username:password@fs-shopping-list.6rzkd.mongodb.net/data?retryWrites=true&w=majority`. I only have one database named `data` and it has a collection called `items`. I'm pretty sure I typed the URI string correctly so that means there must be some network problem. I tried connecting from another network (after adding my new IP address to the whitelist) only for it to still fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example of how I do it with `mongoose`:

```
const connectToMongo = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    console.log('connected to MongoDB');
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('error connection to MongoDB:', error.message);
  }
};
```

Here is an example of the `mongoUrl`: `mongo+srv://username:password@cluster0-ipl5c.mongodb.net/collectionname?retryWrites=true`

**Please** make sure that you create a user to read and write to the database **that isn't the admin account.** The URI string you get from the "Connect" button might use the admin account **even though that's not the account you want to use in the URI string,** so keep that in mind. If you did that and you're still unable to connect, please use this checklist:

- check that correct IP is whitelisted
- check that user has correct rights
- check that you are using the right database name (collection)
- check if you have special characters in your password (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-pass-characters)

[image: Database access management]

[image: Network access management]

[image: Clusters and collections]

Comment: I had clicked the "Add my current IP" button and "Allow access from anywhere" buttons on my cluster before I made this post :(. I think my problem has to do with the URI string I have, judging from what Matt Clark said.

Comment: Am I still able to use Mongoose after using `MongoClient`? I need to be able to use Mongoose's schemas, etc. to follow the tutorial.

Comment: Here I have used mongoose: https://github.com/MarianiGiacomo/Blog-App/tree/master/blog-app-be
I hope it can help you. Under app.js I connect to the database. You can  not see the dbUri in the repo, but it is in the form `mongo+srv://username:password@cluster0-ipl5c.mongodb.net/collectionname?retryWrites=true`

Comment: I have added some pictures. Hopefully they are helpful.

Comment: Okay I finally figured out what the problem was. I was copying the URI string provided when you click on the "Connect" button, and it kept saying to use my **admin** account. I created a new user that only has read-write privileges for the database, used that account in the URI instead, and now it finally works. MongoDB **really** should've made it clearer that the admin account apparently can't be used for reading and writing to the database (even though the documentation I've linked in the post suggests otherwise). Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `dbName` in options:

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017', { dbName: "blog" });
```